# TypeError in showResult for leaflet-geosearch

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-plugins

I'm using leaflet-geosearch. When I click on an address from the search bar, I get the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
> at Function.keys ()
> at NewClass.showResult (SearchControl.ts:412:28)
> at SearchControl.ts:404:12

Here is the code snippet:

```js
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  
  <!--initialize geosearch -->
  <link  href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-geosearch@latest/assets/css/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-geosearch@latest/dist/bundle.min.js"></script>   


var map

function createMap() {

    map = L.map('map').setView([41, -74], 9);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);


    const search = new GeoSearch.GeoSearchControl({
        provider: new GeoSearch.OpenStreetMapProvider(),
        /*not working
        params: {
            countrycodes: 'us'
        },*/
        style: 'bar',
        showMarker: true, // optional: true|false  - default true
        showPopup: false, // optional: true|false  - default false
        marker: {
            // optional: L.Marker    - default L.Icon.Default
            icon: new L.Icon.Default(),
            draggable: false,
        },
    });
    map.addControl(search);


    //not working
    function searchEventHandler(result) {
        console.log(result.location);
    }

    //not working
    map.on('geosearch/showlocation', searchEventHandler);
}
```

Comment: It looks like users are reporting similar issues on Github for that plugin (https://github.com/smeijer/leaflet-geosearch/issues). I suggest keeping tabs on those issues to see if the developers post a fix that could apply to your situation as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. **It was because of a bug in version 3.0.0**. In your case you point the "latest" js file so it should work already.
Here is the article I found my solution:

https://github.com/smeijer/leaflet-geosearch/issues/229